# Messed up my Firefox 4 settings

Tags: settings, firefox

I installed some extensions for Firefox and now my tabs bar is gone and on the left, there are some white pixels where they should be brown. I tried deleting the settings file in etc/firefox/prefs, but without success.

How can I restore the original settings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was Tab Fox, disabled it and everything's fine.

Comment: If this is answer to your question, remember to mark it as answer when you can (after 24 hours, I think).